# converting a Virtualbox to Xenserver

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, virtualbox, vmware-vsphere, xenserver

How can I use my virtualbox image in a Xenserver 6 or above? I mean is there a way to import the image to Xenserver? Secondly is there anyway we can import vmware image to Xenserver without using VSphere as I only use vmware player?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

VirtualBox can export OVF files which *should* successfully import to XenServer.